# Какой алгоритм использовать для построения файлового каталога?

Tags: c#, .net

На входе у меня json массив данных. В каждом элементе имеется `id(string, not null), folder(bool), parentId(string)`

На основе этих данных я должен сформировать файловый каталог(или еще как это называют "дерево"). Аналогия это - файловая система в проводнике *windows*(думаю как и в большинстве ОС). Как создать классы tree, node, leaf я знаю и структуру более менее понимаю. Проблема в алгоритме который раскидывает весь массив в эту структуру.
Можете подсказать как это реализовать или каким алгоритмом?

Comment: вы для начала приведите пример вашего файла. потом пример ваших классов (чем leaf от node отличается?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Проходите по входному массиву, строите ассоциативный массив id -> node (для папок) / lead (для файлов).
2. Проходите по values ассоциативного массива (т.е. по всем папкам и файлам), для каждой находите парента (поиском в ассоциативном массиве по ключу), записываете парента в parent у ноды, ноду - в children у парента (в зависимости от того, как вы данные храните). Ноды без парента связываете с tree.

Готово.